# How to create 'union' of two intersecting CGPath-s?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, cgpath

I wanted to create a rounded cross by combining two rounded rectangles with CGPathAddRoundedRect. The problem is the area where rects intersect is empty, but I would like it to be filled. (see image of the problem)

I'm also using SpriteKit SKShapeNode to draw on scene. Here is Swift code I'm using:

```
    backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    let width: CGFloat = 302
    let height: CGFloat = 92
    let path = CGPathCreateMutable()
    CGPathAddRoundedRect(path, nil, CGRectMake((size.width-width)/2, (size.height-height)/2, width, height), height/2, height/2)
    CGPathAddRoundedRect(path, nil, CGRectMake((size.width-height)/2, (size.height-width)/2, height, width), height/2, height/2)
    CGPathCloseSubpath(path)
    let cross = SKShapeNode(path: path)
    cross.fillColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    addChild(cross)
```

Any ideas how to make intersecting area filled? I know I could create two separate shape nodes ... but I just want to learn how to do that with combining CGPaths directly.

[image]

Comment: you may need to check the `CGContextBlendMode(...)`.

Comment: Duplicate of many: https://www.google.com/search?q=CGPath+union+site%3Astackoverflow.com